# How to add a component with parameters to a gameobject so that I could access it gameobject.newcomponent.myparameter?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am really a newbie in programming and I've been searching the web for at least 1 hour and couldn't find (or maybe understand) anything.

It would be great to see an example.

I am trying to change Time.TimeScale through a tween, but it only allows gameobjects and their parameters as input data

> > HOTween.To(gameObject, duration, parameter, to);

Comment: Hi guys,

I've actually found another method and used a different tween instead - iTween.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/159948/using-itween-for-custom-variables.html

Comment: If you found the solution to your own question you can post it as an answer and even accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually found another method and used a different tween instead - iTween.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/159948/using-itween-for-custom-variables.html